# Query from PHP to PostgreSQL is very slow, how to increase?

Tags: php, postgresql

## PHP:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=test user=test password=test");
$start = microtime(true); 
for($i=1;$i<=5000;$i++) { 
    pg_query("insert into testtb(uid,sid) values($i,$i)"); 
} 
echo ( (microtime(true) - $start) *1000).' ms';
// result: 15504.348993301 ms
```

## PSQL shell:

```
begin for r in 1..5000 loop 
insert into testtb (uid,sid) values(r,r); 
end loop; end; $$; 
// result: 43 ms
```

The `testtb` is simple, only two columns `sid` and `uid`, all indexed. PHP and PG are in same server.
From the testing we can see the Postgres speed is very fast for 5000 records inserting. But when using PHP the speed significantly dropped. Then how can we increase PHP+PG speed?

EDIT: please note the result: PHP - **15504** ms, psql shell - **43** ms

Comment: Why do you perform 5000 seperate insertions instead of one with 5000 value tuples? Are there any indices set? Have you ruled out networking issues?

Comment: If you are populating your Database, have you try to use COPY? It's optimised for loading large number of rows.

Comment: @NicoHaase for testing and compared to shell.

Comment: @abestrad no this is not from real condition but a testing. Note that inserting from psql shell is very fast, so the problem should not come from db itself.

Comment: Is it a fresh table? Have you try to create the indexes after inserting all your rows? creating indexes on pre-existing data is quicker than updating it as each row is inserted.

Comment: @abestrad Yes fresh. It is not an index issue, because psql is fast, as I have said in the question.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a catastrophic round-trip latency issue. your PHP script is running on a separate computer (not 127.0.0.1) i bet? i do wonder, how does this perform in comparison?

```
 $db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=test;', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$start = microtime(true); 
$db->beginTransaction();
$stm=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO testtb(uid,sid) VALUES(?,?)");
for($i=1;$i<=5000;++$i) { 
    $stm->execute(array($i,$i));
} 
$db->commit();
echo ( (microtime(true) - $start) *1000).' ms';
```

EDIT: if they are indeed running on the same computer, my next guess is that your PHP script connects via TCP while PSQL shell connects via a unix socket. unix sockets are much faster than a TCP connections, even on localhost, but i wouldn't expect such a drastic difference - *UNLESS* you have a firewall that intercepts localhost-to-localhost connections, firewalls with issues could cause drastic latency issues, which could explain this. try connecting to a unix socket with PHP instead, eg

```
 $db = new PDO('pgsql:unix_socket=/var/run/postgresql.sock;dbname=test;', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$start = microtime(true); 
$db->beginTransaction();
$stm=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO testtb(uid,sid) VALUES(?,?)");
for($i=1;$i<=5000;++$i) { 
    $stm->execute(array($i,$i));
} 
$db->commit();
echo ( (microtime(true) - $start) *1000).' ms';
```

how does that perform? (should perform even better than the TCP connection, but if you have firewall issues, it could perform *MUCH* better than the TCP connection)

and if you don't know where your pqsql unix socket is, this command usually finds it: `sudo find / -iname "*.sock*" 2 >/dev/null`

(by the way, i think `/var/run/postgresql.sock` is the default location on Debian and Ubuntu systems)

Comment: "PHP and PG are in same server"

Comment: @Elect2 weird. my next guess is that PHP connects via TCP while PSQL shell connects via a unix socket (a unix socket is much faster than a TCP connection, even on localhost), but i wouldn't expect such a drastic difference (unless a firewall is in the way of the TCP connection? a firewall that even intercept localhost-to-localhost connections? they do exist)

Comment: @Elect2 i added info about the tcp-socket vs unix-socket theory, re-read my post

Comment: Should not a firewall issue. I have made the testing on both my own virtualbox and aws ec2, result is same. (ubuntu 16.04, nginx, php7-fpm,pg10). BTW: tested the $db->commit method and it's faster(300ms), but I know it will be faster because it send all queries at once. What I expected is how to increase query by query speed. I've also tested PHP+Mongodb query by query 5000 insert and the result is 150ms.

Comment: @Elect2 hmm.. well, test the speed with a unix socket and let me know how fast that is

Comment: tested socket, result exactly the same, around 15 seconds.

Comment: I'm afraid this result is "normal" for PHP+Postgresql. If you got time please make a test on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this result is **normal**.
When using PHP, the inserting is 1 row per query. I run a TPS benchmark on my PostgreSQL server and the result is around **500** TPS. So that reasonable to spend 15 second for inserting 5000 rows.

As for why the PostgreSQL shell is very fast, I think it is not a loop of queries, but a single bulk query.